# How can I query Windows to determine if there are cached credentials for any given, detected WiFi network?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, wifi

I am working on a tool that needs to manage certain network settings on a user's machine.  One operation I need to be able to execute is "forget" a network.  However, before I give the user an option to forget a network, I need to identify if, for any given detected WiFi network, if there are cached credentials for that specific network.

How can I discern that for any given, discovered network if there is are cached credentials on the given users machine?

Answer (score 0):

WLAN_PROFILE_GET_PLAINTEXT_KEY is a flag in WlanGetProfile read about that here [WlanGetProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706738(v=vs.85).aspx)
If i was on my home PC i would paste you a example from one of my previous projects, i got stuck on this too.